# xslt: xsl:value-of cannot doesnt work inside <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Tags: xml, xslt

my data's xml format is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table_data name="dbTest">
    <row>
        <test name='temp'>
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
                 <p> My data </p>
                 <ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li></ul>      
            </div>
        </test>
        <test name='temp2'>
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
                     <p> Other data </p>
                     <ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li></ul>      
                </div>
        </test>
     </row>
</table_data>
```

I want to extract "My data" inside the `<p>` tag using xslt and format it into another xml format. My .xslt file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<newformat>
  <xsl:for-each select="table_data/row">       
        <text><xsl:value-of select="test[@name='temp']/div/p"/></text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</newformat>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I dont see any result. However if I just use `<xsl:value-of select="test[@name='temp']"/>` I see everything inside the div which is `<p>` and `<ul>` tag.

Any ideas on how I should go about in extracting just the `<p>` from `<div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` elements in your XML and their descendants are in a namespace. You must select them using a prefix bound to the same namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
exclude-result-prefixes="x">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <newformat>
        <xsl:for-each select="table_data/row">       
            <text>
                <xsl:value-of select="test[@name='temp']/x:div/x:p"/>
            </text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </newformat>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```